# Limits of sequences (limit theorems)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So first of all, I am not really sure what (if there even is) a difference between showing the convergence or divergence of a sequence vs the taking the limits of a function like we do in calculus. So if someone could explain the difference to me that would be great.
With that being said, I am really unsure of my work I have done so far.
And finally, I need a refresher on $2^n$ or $n!$ type limits.

For $s_n$ given by the following formulas, determine the convergence or divergence of the sequence $s_n$. Find any limits that exist.

a. $s_n=\frac{3-2n}{1+n}=\frac{3/n-2}{1/n+1}$ 
$lims_n=lim\frac{3/n-2}{1/n+1}=-2$

converges to -2

b. $s_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+3}=\frac{(-1)^n/n}{1+3/n}$
$lims_n=lim\frac{(-1)^n/n}{1+3/n}=0/1+0=0$

converges to 0

c. $s_n=\frac{(-1)^nn}{2n-1}=\frac{(-1)^n1}{2-1/n}$ 
$lims_n=lim\frac{(-1)^n1}{2-1/n}$

diverges with no limit

d. $s_n=\frac{2^{3n}}{3^{2n}}=

???? how can I go about solving this one?

e. $s_n=\frac{n^2-2}{n+1}=\frac{n-2/n}{1+1/n}$

then I am not sure??

f. $s_n=\frac{3+n-n^2}{1+2n}=\frac{(-1)^n1}{2-1/n}$

g. $s_n=\frac{1-n}{2^n}$

h. $s_n=\frac{3^n}{n^3+5}$

i. $s_n=\frac{n!}{2^n}$

j. $s_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$

k. $s_n=\frac{n^2}{2^n}$

l. $s_n=\frac{n^2}{n!}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intial question. 
Calculating the limits is only one of methods of showing that the limit exists. For example, it is easy to show that the sequence
$$
a_n=\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}+\dots+\frac1{n^2}
$$
is convergent, but computing its limit is much more difficult.

And remaining limits:
d) 0, e) $+\infty$, f) $-\infty$, g) 0, h) $+\infty$, i) $+\infty$, j) 0, k) 0, l) 0, if you need answers to control your solutions. The example j) seems to be the hardest one.

Answer (score 0):

for (d), note that $(\frac23)^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$;

for (e), is $+\infty$